# I can't get dragon souls, Miraak keeps stealing them!

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

I've recently started doing the Dragonborn quests in Skyrim, but after the quest 'Temple of Miraak', Miraak steals my dragon souls. Is there any way to stop this apart from killing him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Miraak does not always steal your souls when you kill a dragon in Skyrim.  Also, if you happen to kill a dragon above water, then Miraak will not appear and steal your dragon soul.

Comment: Sorry, I should have said, I have killed around 12 dragons from the time when he first appears, yet I have not one dragon soul! I had heard he stopped after three, but not for me! I am playing on PS4 (Remastered Version)